# Ws02 APIManager in a docker container

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm running Ws02 products in docker containers
I have a strange problem. I publish an API in publisher, subscribe to it using the store and access the API using the curl command. It works fine. The DB is also running in a separate mysql container and Im persisting the DB data to a volume. However, if I shutdown the containers (docker-compose down) , bring it back up and access the API again, I get a 404 error with the following errordetails .Any idea?

errorCode":900000
errorDescription":"Not Found""
errorDetails":"The requested resource is not available
404

Answer (score 0):

In API Manager, some API data is persisted in the File system as well. You can see the artifacts located at "/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api. You need to make sure this is not replaced when the docker container is restarted.